# How to display iOS app passcode lock screen only when App is not visible?

Tags: ios6

I have implemented an app specific Passcode screen that works great and is activated when ApplicationWillResignActive method override on my AppDelegate is invoked.

However this has resulted in some undesirable effects when a Low Battery notification or a notification center message pops up. In both cases, my app screen is visible bit it goes to inactive state.

I want to display the passcode screen only when the app is not visible in the foreground.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Try to add that in delegate method for entering in Background mode and remove it only when you wanted. Dont use ApplicationWillResignActive.